# JQuery foreach count

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, count

I have a piece of code that fetches results from my DB and then shows it on my page via jQuery:

```
var searchItem = function() {
    $('#search_results').css('top', '0px');
    $.getJSON('/json/searchitem/q/' + $('#json_search').val(), function(data){
        $('#search_results ul').fadeIn().html('');

        if($('#search_results table').css('display')=='none'){
            $('#search_results table').fadeIn();
        }

        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            $('#search_results').append('<tr><td>'+item.code+'</td></tr>');
        });
    });
};
```

Now, what I want is when my results are > 10 I want to show it in a table with small rows, 5 to 10 results in a normal table result and < 2 in big divs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this count?
I'm not experienced in JQuery yet.

Comment: I think "data" is an array in your snippet. So why don't use "data.length"?

Comment: as in just data.length < 10 ? Is that a correct format in jQuery?

Comment: Maybe offtopic... But it's better to escape the searchquery before putting it in the url.  You can do that by `encodeURIComponent($('#json_search').val())`
Think what happend if i search for `oh/no/this/is/going/wrong!`

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript library. You can write some JavaScript code into your jQuery one.

Comment: Also... Instead of `.html('')` you can use `.empty()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var searchItem = function() {
    $('#search_results').css('top', '0px');
    $.getJSON('/json/searchitem/q/' + $('#json_search').val(), function(data){
        $('#search_results ul').fadeIn().html('');

        if($('#search_results table').css('display')=='none'){
            $('#search_results table').fadeIn();
        }
       //Checks If result length is lessthan 2
        if(data.length < 2){
            // Show in big divs
        }else{
            //  show it in a table with small rows
             $.each(data, function(i,item){
               $('#search_results').append('<tr><td>'+item.code+'</td></tr>');
             });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`data` is an array, and `data.length` is the number of elements in the array. So you can compare it with your different limit criteria.

```
if (data.length > 10) {
    // Code to show table with small rows
} else if (data.length >= 5) {
    // Code for normal table
} else if (data.length < 2) {
    // Code for big divs
} else {
    // Not sure what you want for 2-4, but this is where it goes
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that it was just the same format as in my php files!

Comment: Javascript and PHP copied most of their basic syntax from C.